# Getting a ResponseStatusLine error when downloading a .json from an api website

Tags: c#, json, http-headers, httprequest

I've been trying to make a small app using the Discogs API for personal use in order to search individual artists and their albums, which worked so far using an unofficial Discogs C# app. Now the issue is that the only way I can extract the tracklist of an album is using the resource URL i get from each album request (for instance, https://api.discogs.com/releases/2890373).

I tried to extract the .json from each URL and I keep getting a ResponseLine error even with appropriate headers.

Added an Authorization header with my consumer key and secret key, lke this:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Discogs key=xxx, secret=yyy");
```

...added a UserAgent and it still does not work.

I've tried the same in Python and it worked perfectly, but I don't want to run a Python app each time I want info about an album.

```
private void scrape_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.discogs.com/releases/2890373");
            httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = 12000;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/vnd.discogs.v2.html+json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "matija_search/0.1");
            string file;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                file = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

This is the button that tries to get the data.

```
import requests
import json
info = requests.get('https://api.discogs.com/releases/2890373')
data = info.json()
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

This is a python equivalent which actually works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, solved the issue.
I did not add the UserAgent in the correct way.
Fixed code is as follows:

```
private void scrape_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.discogs.com/releases/2890373");
            httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.discogs.v2.html+json";
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "matija_search/1";
            string file;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                file = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file);
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.json", false);
            writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
        }
```